# Coding for a calculation in differential geometry using Maple

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, maple, connections

I am beginner in maple. And my field is Differential geometry. I've learnt [lie brackets](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=DifferentialGeometry/LieBracket) using maple help.
But I am testing this calculation through maple.

I have these vector fields 
$e1=z^2\ast D\_x, e2=z^2\ast D\_y, e3=z^2\ast D\_z$

Now I have to calculate $2g(\nabla_{e1}e3,e1)$ using maple. where The Riemannian connection $\nabla$ of the metric tensor $g$ is given by [Koszul's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_Riemannian_geometry)

$2g(\nabla_XY,Z)=X_g(Y,Z)+Y_g(Z,X)-Z_g(X,Y)-g(X,[Y,Z])-g(Y,[X,Z])+g(Z,[X,Y])$

By calculated manually I got  $2g(\nabla_{e1}e3,e1)=2g(-\frac2z e_1,e_1)$

So help me in simplifying tedious calculations using maple. You can just send codes or links. I will try to learn.